# after configuring particles.js via npm. It does not show up on .ejs page

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, npm, particles.js

I set up everything as shown on the Github page using npm since I'm using node.js. https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/ I embedded app.js as a script in the main.ejs. then created a particles.json for the configuration, saved everything, and restarted the server and absolutely nothing happens. I applied some CSS to the container for the particles as height: 100% but still nothing the GitHub page does a poor job explaining. Can anyone tell where I am going wrong with the configuration?
[ed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rc2un.png)

**views/main.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">
    <title>Anthony Tejada</title>

    <!--Template based on URL below-->
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/starter-template/">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Place your stylesheet here-->
    <link href="/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md  ">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TEJADA</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault">
            <span>
                <div class="burger-menu"></div>
                <div class="burger-menu"></div>
                <div class="burger-menu"></div>
            </span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Skills</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Education</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--jumbotron/header-->
    <div class="jumbotron ">

        <div id="particles-container">
            <img src="<%=images.pic%>" alt="" class="mypic shadow">
            <h4 class="header-text">Hello, I am Anthony Tejada a Junior </h4>
            <hr class="header-line">
            <h3 class="header-text-big">Web Developer</h3>
            <button type="button" class=" header-btn">Discover Me!</button>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="portfolio-section-header">

        </div>

    </div>



    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/particles.js/particles.js"></script>
    <script>
        particlesJS.load('particles-container"', 'particles.json', function() {
            console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
        });

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**particles.json** in root. I created and copy and pasted the json from github

```
{
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 80,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 800
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": "#ffffff"
    },
    "shape": {
      "type": "circle",
      "stroke": {
        "width": 0,
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 5
      },
      "image": {
        "src": "img/github.svg",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100
      }
    },
    "opacity": {
      "value": 0.5,
      "random": false,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 1,
        "opacity_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "value": 10,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 80,
        "size_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "line_linked": {
      "enable": true,
      "distance": 300,
      "color": "#ffffff",
      "opacity": 0.4,
      "width": 2
    },
    "move": {
      "enable": true,
      "speed": 12,
      "direction": "none",
      "random": false,
      "straight": false,
      "out_mode": "out",
      "bounce": false,
      "attract": {
        "enable": false,
        "rotateX": 600,
        "rotateY": 1200
      }
    }
  },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": false,
        "mode": "repulse"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "push"
      },
      "resize": true
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 800,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "bubble": {
        "distance": 800,
        "size": 80,
        "duration": 2,
        "opacity": 0.8,
        "speed": 3
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 400,
        "duration": 0.4
      },
      "push": {
        "particles_nb": 4
      },
      "remove": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "retina_detect": true
}
```

**index.js**

```
var Express = require("express");
var app =Express();
var port = process.env.PORT ||3000;

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use(Express.static("public"));
var images ={

 pic:"/images/pic.png",
 menu_btn:"/images/menu-btn.png"
}

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render("main",{images:images});
});

app.listen(port, function(){

    console.log("Server started !")
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Anthony",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "particles.js": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

**index.css**

```
#particles-container{

    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Do you have errors in the console of your browser's dev tools? Or errors in the network panel? And/or a working example on a code playground could help also.

Comment: Yes, I am getting console errors just added the image link under "ed". I will try and get it on a code playground.

Comment: I am thinking I need to serve static files https://www.tutorialspoint.com/expressjs/expressjs_static_files.htm